# $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^k$ but $\alpha$ inconstructible

Tags: galois-theory

While doing Galoistheory I came across this question:

Find $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^k$ but $\alpha$ inconstructible.

I know $\alpha$ is inconstructible if the Galoisgroup of its minimal polynomial is not of order a power of $2$.

I believe $\zeta_6 \cdot \sqrt{2}$ works, because its minimal polynomial is $f = X^4 + 2X^2 + 4$ and its splitting field $L$ I believe is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6, \sqrt{2})$ with $[L : \mathbb{Q}] = 2\cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]$ and that makes that degree $6$? Because $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})] = 3$ with minimal polynomial $X^3 + 1 = 0$.

However, I often make mistakes while doing Galoistheory, so am I doing this correct?

Comment: But $\zeta_6\cdot\sqrt{2}$ manifestly is constructible with a straight edge and a compass.

Comment: Yes, $\zeta_6$ is constructible, as is $\sqrt{2}$, so their product has to be. Also, that polynomial is clearly solvable with square roots. First solve $Y^2+2Y+4$, then take the square root of $Y$ to get a root.

Comment: Aha yes, I was to stuck in my maths to see that obvious conclusion. But the question of course still remains.

Comment: Since there is a solution to the general quartic equation with square roots, you'll need to go to degree $8$, and find one that cannot be solved by radicals.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I take a look at the "general solution" and it involves cubic roots. So I think a carefully chosen one might work.

Comment: If you can find an irreducible quartic polynomial with Galois group $G = A_4$ or $G = S_4$, then any root of that polynomial will do the trick. Consider the Galois correspondence between subgroups of $G$ and subfields of the Galois closure. $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ corresponds to a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with index four. If $\alpha$ were constructible, there would have to be some subgroup intermediate between $H$ and $G$. But there isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having spoken to my professor about this problem he proposed the following solution:

Pick $f(x) = x^4 + bx + c$ such that $f$ is irreducible and its Galois-group is either $S_4$ or $A_4$ (just as user208259 mentioned in the comments) and then just pick $\alpha$ as $f(\alpha) = 0$. Trying to write out this $\alpha$ is useless as it is often just horrible. To establish the Galois-group you could use the Resolvent Cubic to make that easier.

$f(x) = x^4 + 3x + 1$ should do the trick.

Comment: This works (+1). The reason is that $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha):\Bbb{Q}]=4$, but there is no intermediate quadratic field that constructibility requires. As suspected, this is better explained using Galois correspondence to translate it into the language of groups. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/354098/11619) for a bit of discussion and generalizations.